# Unwanted, and unwarranted?, indent after \section

Tags: spacing, sectioning, indentation

I've got a template for my CV which I grabbed from somewhere years ago, and the preamble has been mostly added to, with bits being modified along the way.  I thought enough is enough so I have set about creating a document class.  Now my cv.tex file has effectively no preamble, and the class file is much better structured and more readable.

Somewhere I have introduced a problem: the first line of text after a `\section` is indented a little, see:

[image: Indented first line]

See that the ‘C’ of “Computer” and the ‘G’ of “General” are indented slightly from the rest of the text.

---

The `\section` has been redefined such that it appears in the “marginal notes”, which has been forced onto the left hand side:

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \pagebreak[2]
    \vspace{0\baselineskip}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \hspace{0mm}
    \marginpar{
        \raggedright
        \scshape #1
    }
}
```

But it is unchanged from the original preamble.

---

### Logs

Looking at the output logs, here's two excerpts:

```
\blankline -> \par \vspace {2mm} \pagebreak [2] 
{blank space  }
{\par}
@firstpass
[]  []\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 General Computing 
@\penalty via @@0 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@1: line 1.2 t=100 -> @@0
@secondpass
[]  []\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 General Com-put-ing 
@\penalty via @@0 b=0 p=-10000 d=*
@@1: line 1.2 t=0 -> @@0
```

The above shows the log output for some bold text "General Computing".

```
\blankline -> \par \vspace {2mm} \pagebreak [2] 
{blank space  }
{\par}
@firstpass
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 Learning and Teaching 
@\penalty via @@0 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@1: line 1.2 t=100 -> @@0
```

The above shows the log output for some bold text further down the same `\section`
I note that in the first example I have `[]  []\0T1...` whereas in the second I simply have `[]\0T1...`

---

### Code

The document class is here in its entirety:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Optionals %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{10pt}{article}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{article}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}}

\ProcessOptions


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Class Particulars %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Loads a “base class” which we can modify.
\LoadClass{article}
\ProcessOptions

% Class requirements and description
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{bil-CV}[2015/03/22 Ben Lavery’s CV Class]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Required Packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% This is a helpful package that puts math inside length specifications
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc
\RequirePackage{calc}

% Good for playing with paper sizes
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\RequirePackage{geometry}

% For hyperlinks in text
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

% To remove headers and footers
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Lengths %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Half of the page width, useful for ‘false columns’
\newlength{\halfpage}
\setlength{\halfpage}{(\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep)/2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Puts the section titles on left side of page
% Section titles are in the margin
\reversemarginpar

% Set up the margins/etc
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    marginparwidth=20mm,  % Length of section titles (marginal note width)
    marginparsep=4mm,     % Separation between the marginal note and main text
    margin=12mm,          % margins (all)
    includemp,            % Include marginal note in textwidth calculations
}

% Stop indenting throughout entire document
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

% Stop hyphens
%\hyphenpenalty=10000
%\exhyphenpenalty=10000

% Remove header and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New Commands & Environments %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% The title (name) with a horizontal rule under it
% Usage: \makeheading{name}
% Place at top of document. It should be the first thing.
\newcommand{\makeheading}[1]{
    \hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
        {\large \bfseries #1}\\
        [-0.15\baselineskip]
        \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
}

% To add some paragraph space between lines.
% This also tells LaTeX to preferably break a page on one of these gaps
% if there is a needed pagebreak nearby.
\newcommand{\blankline}{

    \vspace{2mm}
    \pagebreak[2]
}

% Adds a short line between ‘subsections’
\newcommand{\subsectionrule}{

    \vspace{-2.5mm}\rule{300px}{0.5px}\vspace{1mm}

}

% Adds thinspace around an en-dash for dates containing months
\newcommand{\daterange}[2]{
    #1\thinspace--\thinspace#2
}

% Add contact information in a ‘nice’ way
\newcommand{\contactdetails}[8]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\halfpage}
        %\twocolumn
        #4\\
        #5\\
        #6\\
        #7\\
        #8
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\halfpage}
        \textit{Phone}: #1\\
        \textit{E-mail}: \href{#2}{#2}\\
        \textit{WWW}: \href{#3}{#3}
    \end{minipage}
}

% Add the ‘head’ section for education/work places
\newcommand{\placementheader}[4]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \textbf{#1}, {\daterange{#2}{#3}}\\
        #4
    \end{minipage}
}

% Add the ‘head’ section for education/work places
\newcommand{\placementheaderonedate}[3]{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \textbf{#1}, {#2}\\
        #3
    \end{minipage}
}

% Use a normal itemised list, but compact the space between bullets to
% ‘normal’ line spacing.
\newenvironment{compactlist}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{ 
    \end{itemize}
}

% Use a normal itemised list, but compact the space between bullets to
% ‘normal’ line spacing.  Use this INSIDE other compact lists.
\newenvironment{innercompactlist}{
    \vspace{0in}
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}{ 
    \end{itemize}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Renew Commands & Environments %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Otherwise the top of the section header will not line up with the top
% of the section.
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \pagebreak[2]
    \vspace{0\baselineskip}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
    \hspace{0mm}
    \marginpar{
        \raggedright
        \scshape #1
    }
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    \textbf{#1}\\
}
```

While the old preamble is here:

```
% Don't like 10pt? Try 11pt or 12pt
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% This is a helpful package that puts math inside length specifications
\usepackage{calc}

%Provides multi-line comments
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{multicol}

% Simpler bibsection for CV sections
% (thanks to natbib for inspiration)
\makeatletter
\newlength{\bibhang}
\setlength{\bibhang}{1em}
\newlength{\bibsep}
 {\@listi \global\bibsep\itemsep \global\advance\bibsep by\parsep}
\newenvironment{bibsection}
    {\minipage[t]{\linewidth}\list{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
        }}
    {\endlist\endminipage}
\makeatother

% Layout: Puts the section titles on left side of page
\reversemarginpar


%% Use these lines for A4-sized paper
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
            %includefoot, % Uncomment to put page number above margin
            marginparwidth=20mm,    % Length of section titles
            marginparsep=4mm,       % Space between titles and text
            margin=12.04mm,              % margins
            includemp]{geometry}
%% More layout: Get rid of indenting throughout entire document
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

%% This gives us fun enumeration environments. compactitem will be nice.
\usepackage{paralist}

%% Reference the last page in the page number
%
% NOTE: comment the +LP line and uncomment the -LP line to have page
%       numbers without the ``of ##'' last page reference)
%
% NOTE: uncomment the \pagestyle{empty} line to get rid of all page
%       numbers (make sure includefoot is commented out above)
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{empty}      % Uncomment this to get rid of page numbers
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
          {0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
       \parbox{4in}{\, \hfill %
                    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage} % +LP
%                    \arabic{page}                               % -LP
                    \hfill \,}}

% Finally, give us PDF bookmarks
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Document Setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                   CUSTOM STUFF
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newenvironment{my_itemize}{
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}{\end{itemize}
}

\hyphenpenalty=10000    %Stop hyphens
\exhyphenpenalty=10000  %Stop hyphens


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Helper Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% The title (name) with a horizontal rule under it
%
% Usage: \makeheading{name}
%
% Place at top of document. It should be the first thing.
\newcommand{\makeheading}[1]%
        {\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
         \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
                {\large \bfseries #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
                 \rule{\columnwidth}{1pt}%
         \end{minipage}}

% The section headings
%
% Usage: \section{section name}
%
% Follow this section IMMEDIATELY with the first line of the section
% text. Do not put whitespace in between. That is, do this:
%
%       \section{My Information}
%       Here is my information.
%
% and NOT this:
%
%       \section{My Information}
%
%       Here is my information.
%
% Otherwise the top of the section header will not line up with the top
% of the section. Of course, using a single comment character (%) on
% empty lines allows for the function of the first example with the
% readability of the second example.
\renewcommand{\section}[2]%
        {\pagebreak[2]\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
         \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
         \hspace{0in}%
         \marginpar{
         \raggedright \scshape #1}#2}

% An itemize-style list with lots of space between items
\newenvironment{outerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1]}{\end{itemize}%
         \vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to outerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{lonelist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{list}{#1}{%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
        {\end{list}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% An itemize-style list with little space between items
\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{compactitem}[#1]}{\end{compactitem}}

% An environment IDENTICAL to innerlist that has better pre-list spacing
% when used as the first thing in a \section
\newenvironment{loneinnerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{compactitem}[#1]}
        {\end{compactitem}\vspace{-.6\baselineskip}}

% To add some paragraph space between lines.
% This also tells LaTeX to preferably break a page on one of these gaps
% if there is a needed pagebreak nearby.
\newcommand{\blankline}{\quad\pagebreak[2]}

% Uses hyperref to link DOI
\newcommand\doilink[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\newcommand\doi[1]{doi:\doilink{#1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End Helper Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

And an excerpt from my document which has remained unchanged:

```
%***********************************************************************
%************************** Begin Interests ****************************
%***********************************************************************
\section{Interests}
% <- SPACES BETWEEN HEADER AND CONTENT TO KEEP CORRECT SPACING!
\subsection{General Computing}
Automation and scripting are
```

Comment: Your definition are void of any space-saving `%`s. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://goo.gl/awJkj) You'll need it in certain places, otherwise it may force unwanted (spurious) spaces.

Comment: \*falls over\* thank you so much!  Would be able to whack that in an answer so I can mark it as correct?